# Chrome cannot inspect webpages on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, portforwarding, inspect

[image: Chrome CAN detect opened webpages on device but CANNOT inspect them]

Like the image above. Chrome CAN detect opened webpages on device but CANNOT inspect them (click 'inspect' and the opened page is constantly loading and there is no content on it).
The reason may be that my PC that is running Chrome has no Internet access, or that ports of it is limited by my company for security reasons. So how can I inspect the html of my webpage shown on my Android device?
1. Port forwarding may be a solution. Who can tell me how please? I tried but failed. 
2. I can't load the help page about port forwarding (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#reverse-port-forwarding). Who can send me the content (mailto: xyxzfj@gmail.com)? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last step needs to visit https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com. 
If you cannot open the link, that's why you got an empty window. In this case maybe you need a VPN. This is really a problem for people in China because the appspot.com domain is blocked by [GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Shield_Project). So sad.